# Java RequestBypassToServer NoClassDefFoundError

Tags: java, python

At least 4 times i am getting this error.
And i dont know why i am getting this error.
The 95% of the Project is working at some point i am getting this specific error.

i tryed to solve own my own but i couldn't

```
[31/07 06:05:17] Client: [Wife: Jessica Brown - Costumer Accunt: Philip Marine - IP: 84.34.12.67] - Failed reading: [C] 21 RequestBypassToServer ; org/omg/PortableServer/POAManagerPackage/State
    java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/omg/PortableServer/POAManagerPackage/State
```

Comment: 1) Does the "python" tag have any relevance to this question?  2) Tell us what version of Java you are using to run this, and show us the command line that is being executed to run this.  3)  The title doesn't match the log message.  Please explain.  4) Please include full (unedited) stacktraces in your questions.

Comment: Thanks your interest I have found the solution / problem. The problem is using Liberica OpenJDK to compile project. I have Uninstall that. And install Java from oracle and problem fixed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the solution / problem. The problem is using Liberica OpenJDK to compile project. I have Uninstall that. And install Java from oracle and problem fixed –

Comment: I am guessing, but a more likely explanation is the Java *version number*.  CORBA support was removed in Java 11, and the exception implies that your application depends on CORBA classes.  (I don't know whether that dependency is necessary ... because you have given us so little information.)